# Convert SQL subquery to EF Query using Lambda syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is SQL Query,,, I have two `tables, one is Categories and other Sub Categories`,,, I want to use `inner query(Category table) and that value pass to outer query(Sub categories table)`
How to convert it into Entity framework with lambda expression..?

```
select * 
from DC_System_SubCategories 
where CatID = (select max(CatID) 
               from DC_System_Categories)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presuming `DCSystemSubcategories` is an `IEnumerable<DCSystemSubcategory>` with appropriate properties, and `DCSystemCategories` is a related `IEnumerable<DCSystemCategory>`:

```
var subcategoriesWithMaxCatId = DCSystemSubcategories
                           Where(x=>x.CatID ==
                                 DCSystemCategories.Max(sc=>sc.CatID))
```

But there are stability concerns depending on how you populate `DCSystemSubcategories`, so expect to do some other logic; also if CatID can be repeated the results are non-deterministic.

Edited: because Magnus pointed out the superior conversion in a comment.
And to illustrate the detail in the question we'd overlooked...

Comment: And if `CatId` is non unique and you want all matching: `var q = DC_System_SubCategories.Where(x => x.CatID == DC_System_SubCategories.Max(p => p.CatID));`

Comment: thanks sir.............but I wan to get the Max id from Categories table and then pass it to Subcategories table

Comment: Really, it's just a matter of using the IEnumerable you want to search for the `IEnumerable<T>`.Max call.

Comment: thanks its working.. like this way...here db=database name......................................................var result = db.DC_System_SubCategories.Where(p => p.CatID == (db.DC_System_Categories.Min(s => s.CatID))).ToList();